# Dodge Diesel 2.0l little acceleration in drive or reverse with black smoke

Tags: diesel, acceleration, smoke

Dodge 2.0 l Journey Diesel engine revs ok in neutral up to 5000 with a very tiny bit of black smoke when it its around the3000- 4000 rpm range ....a little bit of a stutter sometimes but not all times....    but when I put it into drive or reverse (Automatic) it will have hardly any acceleration it will labor slowly increasing rpm to 2000 then drop to 1500 with lots of black smoke out of exhaust and absolutely little to no power ....also no engine light is ever displayed.

I have taken off the airflow sensor and disconnected the filter box and it didn’t make a difference and I did also try cleaning the sensor which also didn’t make a difference.

Any suggestions as to what the problem could be or next item to check ?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Does this engine have a turbocharger? If so, examine the pressure side piping (between the turbo and the intake manifold). It sounds like you have a leak.

Comment: I assume that it you've had this vehicle for a while and it performed better in the past??  But you want to check the basics first.  Check the AIR FILTER and intake paths for any obstructions.  The fact that you have lots of smoke leads me to believe you have a fuel-rich condition that can be caused by a problem with the air intake.

Comment: Yes car is turbo, have checked air-filter, good suction of air pulling through the air intake pipe to turbo. Did a simple diy smoke leak test can see smoke exiting from the air intake side of the turbo. It's hard to see seems to be leaking at turbo, the OBD reader at idle it displays air intake flow rate  8.63 intake manifold 101...boost pressure -0.3 at acceleration in gear turbo pressure rise to +0.3 + 0.2 then engine will drop down in revs again ruff engine with lots of black smoke....in not sure how to upload images :) ?Thanks again for help in this crazy virus times. @jw20